# jquery datepicker trigger next month event

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In my inline datepicker there are the previous en next month buttons, the trigger an event so that the datepicker goes one month further (or back). I want to create an own custom button for next month. What is the event i have to trigger?

Comment: If you're keeping the built-in prev/next month buttons you can just trigger a click event on them.

Comment: I also use that, but a second button has to do the same...